# fitting a betareg model with weights in R

Tags: weights, beta-regression

I am using the `betareg` package in R to model a proportional response and would like to incorporate information about the level of confidence in each observation using the `weights` argument in the `betareg()` function. The package documentation describes the weights as "case weights" and I have read a bit about how this is different from "proportionality weights". However, I am still a bit uncertain if I am using the `weights` argument correctly.

Specifically, each observation in my model is an average of 1-3 (non-independent) measurements. Observations based on 3 measurements are much more reliable than observations based on 1 measurement. This is both because of the greater precision afforded by additional measurements and also because observations based on 1 measurement are inherently more likely to be noisy. My current approach to account for this is to fit a model like this,

```
betareg(y ~ x1, weights = n.obs/3)
```

where 'n.obs' is a vector giving the number of measurements contributing to each observation. The effect on my model seems reasonable - group means are shifted toward more reliable observations and standard errors increase. However, the specific weighting seems a bit arbitrary because I do not know specifically how the number of measurements should affect the standard error of the model parameters. I  am wondering if my current approach is defensible, or whether there is a more appropriate way to specify the weights in this circumstance.

EDIT (to clarify my question): My (probably naive) interpretation of the proposed approach is that observations with only 1 measurement are weighted as 1/3 the "importance" of an observation with all 3 measurements. Is that technically correct? If so, that weighting seems fairly conservative to me. My intuition about this particular data set is that having 1 measurement is at least half the value of a complete set of measurements and the loss of precision is greater dropping from 2 to 1 vs 3 to 2 measurements. I considered scaling the values to reflect this, but I would like to understand the mathematical implications of this in order to justify any possible scaling of the weights.

Comment: From what you're telling us, this seems reasonable and looks a lot like how one would weight observations in something like a logistic regression.

Comment: I edited the post to make my question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that your strategy is reasonable for obtaining the point estimates but some care is needed for obtaining standard errors that might be useful.

`betareg` uses *case weights* and hence a weight of, say, `2` would be interpreted as two independent observations that have exactly the same `y` and `x` values. Thus, these would not just be averages from different observations but exact replicates.

Therefore, if you fit a `betareg` where all observations have weight `2` the coefficients would be unchanged (compared to the default case with weight `1`) but all (co-)variances would be halved.

One strategy that you see sometimes used in practice when emulating *proportionality weights* via *case weights* is to make sure that your weights are scaled such that `sum(weights)` corresponds to the number of independent observations.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms my understanding of the use of weights.